# pip install --user reports successful installation but nothing's there

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I'm need to run a python program on a compute cluster (Linux) where my user does not have root privileges.

The program depends on scipy and some other libraries that are not already installed on the system.

So I tried installing scipy (and the other dependencies) using:

`pip install --user scipy`

which is supposed to install the software in my home directory: ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

(I'm using python 2.7.)

The command executes without an error, reporting successful installation.

However, when I visit my .local directory, the packages are not there. And when I try to import them into a python session, I get an error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please type `pip -V`on your terminal, because what I'm thinking is that pip is for python 3.x or another version than the one you have, please check that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: $ pip -V
gives the pip for python 2.7 - same as system python

Comment: Can you check if you package is not in: /sw/packages/python/2.7.13-1/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - advice from systems administrator:

"Delete your ~/.pydistutils.cfg file and pip install it again."

The file contained this text:

```
[install]
install_lib     = ~/.python/$py_version_short/site-packages
install_platlib = ~/.python/$py_version_short/site-packages
install_scripts = ~/bin
```

Turns out pip was installing the libraries in ~/.python, a location ignored by python on my system.